# set XML attribute value with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to read, modify, and save (override) my `svg` file with `BeautifulSoup` in Python.

Contents of `bs-test.svg`:

```
<g data-default-color="#FFFFFF" data-element-id="X123456">
  <rect class="selection-box" fill="none" height="91" stroke="none" width="140" x="-30" y="-10"/>
  <circle cx="40" cy="25" data-colored="true" fill="red" pointer-events="visible" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
  <text fill="black" font-family="Verdana" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" x="40" y="55">
    <tspan dy="16" x="40">Label Text</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

The contents are actually a subset of a larger svg, where I find `g` elements based on user-provided `data-element-id` values.
I'd like to change the `fill` attribute of the `circle` element to "blue".

what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("bs-test.svg", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = bs(contents, "xml")

# grab g tags with the required data-element-id
elem_ls = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-element-id" : "X123456"})
x = elem_ls[0]
x
```

Output

```
<g data-default-color="#FFFFFF" data-element-id="X123456">
<rect class="selection-box" fill="none" height="91" stroke="none" width="140" x="-30" y="-10"/>
<circle cx="40" cy="25" data-colored="true" fill="red" pointer-events="visible" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
<text fill="black" font-family="Verdana" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" x="40" y="55">
<tspan dy="16" x="40">Label Text</tspan>
</text>
</g>
```

I'm sure that this is just a syntax question that I can't quite find the answer to; how might I go about grabbing the `fill` attr of `circle`, replacing its value with "blue", then writing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the attribute value of the bs4 element using key

**CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("bs-test.svg", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = bs(contents, "xml")

# grab g tags with the required data-element-id
elem_ls = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-element-id" : "X123456"})
for e in elem_ls:
    circle = e.find('circle')
    circle['fill'] = 'blue'

    print(e)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
<g data-default-color="#FFFFFF" data-element-id="X123456">
<rect class="selection-box" fill="none" height="91" stroke="none" width="140" x="-30" y="-10"/>
<circle cx="40" cy="25" data-colored="true" fill="blue" pointer-events="visible" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
<text fill="black" font-family="Verdana" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle" x="40" y="55">
<tspan dy="16" x="40">Label Text</tspan>
</text>
</g>
```